# Cramps vs Abdomen ache

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

Imagine you a woman who is on her period time. Her menstruation has always been very painful. Which one of the following sentences would be idiomatically acceptable to indicate that the woman is having pain right now:

> - I’ve got [cramps](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cramp?q=cramps) because I’m having my period.
> - I’ve got abdomen ache because I’m having my period.
> - I have pain in my abdomen because I’m having my period.

I don't know if the mens. pain has something to do with abdomen in English logic at all or not, but it would be possible for us to say such a thing in our language.

Comment: Nothing for **abdomen ache**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abdomen+ache%2Cbelly+ache&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelly%20ache%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you @TRomano. You helped me a lot. I didn't know that. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first one is most common.

> I’ve got cramps because I’m having my period.

The third is also acceptable, but the second is not something most native speakers would say.

More often they would use the word **stomach** in place of abdomen too.

Comment: But logically there is nothing to do with "stomach" at all. Do you agree @Curtis White?

Comment: Abdomen is a more formal term. Native speakers often use stomach as a general term for that part of the body.